# Drools project throws "The Eclipse JDT Core jar is not in the classpath"

Tags: eclipse, drools, eclipse-jdt

When I run the sample Drools project in Eclipse, it throws an Exception "The Eclipse JDT Core jar is not in the classpath". I have created the Drools 6 runtime manually. Am I missing something?

Full stacktrace

```
org.drools.core.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration'
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:360)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildDialectConfigurationMap(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:346)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:228)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:196)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:152)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieModule.java:166)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.createKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:244)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:204)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:347)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:322)
    at com.sample.ProcessTest.main(ProcessTest.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The Eclipse JDT Core jar is not in the classpath
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration.setCompiler(JavaDialectConfiguration.java:100)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration.init(JavaDialectConfiguration.java:61)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:356)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the Ecliose jdt core jar. Add yhat jar and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I added the org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.7.1.jar and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Added the org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.7.1.jar file to the buildpath of the project and it works perfectly fine. Not sure why this was not part of the Drools runtime which i created manually.